# Is there any installler available for Time Scale DB be installed open-SUSE/SLES?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, postgres-10

Is there any postgres and Time Scale DB installer available for the open-SUSE/SLES-15.
There are some ways available to install postgres using source and then TSDB also but is there an installer available to do so?

Comment: Isn't timescale just an extension? So all that would be required is to copy it into the correct location and then run `create extension timescaledb`?

Comment: Your question isn't a good fit for SO; You're asking us about installers for a specific system.

Comment: try asking for help at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: There are also [docker-containers](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/getting-started/installation/docker/installation-docker) available.